# Change the color of a shape inside a subgroup in VBA for Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, vba7

Hello I would like to change the color of a specific shape called "icon1" which is in a group called "Box1" but this "Box1" is in a group called "BigBox1" (So icon1 is in a subgroup). There is also other shapes and text boxes in the group "Box1" (other shapes:"icon2","icon3"/ "text1", "text2") which I don't want to change the color. I have tried to change the color of the "icon1" but VBA told me that the item with this name could not be found.

```
Sub changeshapecolorinsubgroup()
ActiveDocument.Shapes("BigBox1").GroupItems("Box1").GroupItems("icon1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 200, 128)
End Sub
```

I don't know how to fix my problem, could you help me?

Comment: Try this `ActiveDocument.Shapes("BigBox1").GroupItems("icon1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 200, 128)`

Comment: I am assuming that `BigBox1` is the name of the final shaperange which has all the above items. If you are not sure what is the name of the big group then select it and in vba editor type this `?Selection.ShapeRange.Name`

Comment: And you are totally right, it's working. Thank you so much ;)

Comment: I have put it as an answer in case the above comment is lost. Also the answer can help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

When you group all these shapes, it becomes one shaperange. I am assuming that `BigBox1` is the name of the final shaperange which has all the above items. If you are not sure what is the name of the big group then select it and in vba editor type this

```
?Selection.ShapeRange.Name
```

Finally you can achieve what you want using this

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes("BigBox1").GroupItems("icon1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 200, 128)
```